# Onesignal Web Push

Tags: html, api

Galera estou tentando utilizar Onesginal Web mas não funciona, aparece o icone embaixo mas não faz nada.

Ja esta tudo configurado no site "onesignal"

Onesignal esta fazendo uma chamada acredito que deva estar com problemas. Esta passando na url undefined.

http://localhost/undefined/undefined?appId=xxxxxx

`


    
        
        Onesignal Push Notification

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js" async="" ></script> -->


    <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
    <script>
      var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
      OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.init({
          appId: "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
          autoRegister: false,
          allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
          notifyButton: {
            enable: true,
          },
        });
      });
    </script>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira. Criei no site onesignal o web push do tipo  "Typical Site" e a funcionalidade de se inscrever somente irá funcionar se a sua url for "https".

Nota: deve ser adicionado a url que o onesignal devera apontar em "Site url"

Caso queira pegar o userId gerado pelo onesignal, segue a função:

```
function getUserId() {
    var OneSignal = window['OneSignal'] || [];
    OneSignal.push(function() {
      /* These examples are all valid */
      OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
        console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);
      });

      OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId) {
        console.log("OneSignal User ID:", userId);
      });
    });
}
```